# Match word anywhere within two markers, delimited by whitespace or the markers

Tags: regex, sed

Using Gnu `sed`, can I replace a word only if it appears between two markers (but *anywhere* between them), only if that word is delimited on the left by the starting marker or whitespace and delimited on the right by the ending marker or whitespace? Very similar to using `\b` on either side of the word (between the markers), but only allowing whitespace (or nothing, if adjacent to the starting/ending marker) as a delimiter. `\b` marks the boundary between "word" and "non-word" characters, and treats `-` as a non-word character, which is undesired in this case. Work and results so far, and test cases, below.

*[Detail: Specifically, I'm trying to replace classes within the `class="..."` text in HTML files with other classes. This may be **yet another example** of "don't use regex to work with HTML," but the problem is so contained (I don't care if it happens to match outside a start tag, for instance; I don't care about nesting), it feels like it should be possible and, if possible, would be preferred to my next option, Jsoup (however cool and enticing that is). And it feels like a regex and/or `sed` learning opportunity.]*

The starting marker is:

```
\(\sclass\s*=\s*"\)
```

*(yes, I need to capture it)*.

The ending marker is:

```
"
```

...where no `"` are allowed in-between (whether escaped in some way or not). So nice and contained, not requiring proper parsing. (I'll use a second command to handle the single quotes version.)

I want to match things like this *(for example, there are several of them)*:

```
span\([0-9]\+\)
```

Here's what I have so far, changing `spanN` to `col-md-N` (but using `\b`, and thus not quite working correctly):

```
s/\(\sclass\s*=\s*"\)\([^"]*\)\bspan\([0-9]\+\)\b\([^"]*\)"/\1\2col-md-\3\4"/g
```

And it works nicely for this sample data:

```html
<div class="blah span3 arg">This has span3 in it</div>
<div class="span3">This has span3 in it</div>
<div class="span3 arg">This has span3 in it</div>
```

Giving me the desired:

```html
<div class="blah col-md-3 arg">This has span3 in it</div>
<div class="col-md-3">This has span3 in it</div>
<div class="col-md-3 arg">This has span3 in it</div>
```

But of course it would also change the following:

```html
<div class="blah x-span3 arg">This has x-span3 in it</div>
<div class="x-span3">This has x-span3 in it</div>
<div class="x-span3 arg">This has x-span3 in it</div>
<div class="blah span3-x arg">This has span3-x in it</div>
<div class="span3-x">This has span3-x in it</div>
<div class="span3-x arg">This has span3-x in it</div>
```

...which is not desired. And it goes without saying that `xxxspan3` should also be left alone (which the `\b` version does, of course).

Is it possible to make it *not* change those? Without repeating the expression three times for the "at the beginning", "in the middle", and "at the end" cases? (Six times, if you count the single quotes permutations. *Dozens* of times if you count everything else I need to change.)

If the answer really is "no, you can't," well, that's a perfectly acceptable answer and I'll get a bigger hammer.

---

Epilogue: FYI, this was indeed Yet Another Case of "don't try to process HTML with regular expressions." While Jerry's answer did indeed do what I needed, the further I got into it the clearer it became that I needed more context than regex could give me. I ended up using NodeJS with the `cheerio` DOM parser, because `cheerio` is very good at being minimal with its changes to the markup.

Comment: Are you looking to keep this to one command, and `sed` only?

Comment: @C.B.: Ideally. :-) I'll already have to repeat commands for the various changes being made, and for double- and single-quote versions. So an explosion of permutations (whether as individual commands or unwieldy alternations) probably pushes this into "do it a different way" territory...

Comment: How about [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/kF7iX9)? (I just had to add a `>` to the last negated class so the match doesn't bleed onto other lines. You can ignore that char).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
s/\(\sclass\s*=\s*"\)\(\([^"]*\)\( \)\)\?span\([0-9]\+\)\(\( \)\([^"]*\)\)\?"/\1\3\4col-md-\5\7\8"/g
```

[Sorry it's a big long]

I started out with (with highlighted changes):

```
s/\(\sclass\s*=\s*"\?\)\([^"]*\)\([" ]\)span\([0-9]\+\)\([" ]\)\([^"]*\)/\1\2\3col-md-\4\5\6/g
                   ^^           ^^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^         ^
```

Where I attempted to capture the `"` or the preceding space before `span` and any of the two which followed the digit from `span`. That also called for adding more backreferences in the replace and the removal of the last quote for which the regex had to be adjusted for, but since `class=span` isn't qualified to pass, I realised I couldn't just make the first quote optional or remove the last quote.

I thus removed the quotes from the capture groups:

```
s/\(\sclass\s*=\s*"\)\([^"]*\)\( \)span\([0-9]\+\)\(" \)\([^"]*\)"/\1\2\3col-md-\4\5\6"/g
                              ^^^^^                ^^^^^
```

Now, there was only the quotes to deal with. Since we can have only `"span ...` or `span\d+"`, it meant that everything in between could be made optional:

```
s/\(\sclass\s*=\s*"\)\(\(\([^"]*\)\( \)\)\?span\([0-9]\+\)\(\(" \)\([^"]*\)\)\?"/\1\2\3col-md-\4\5\6"/g
                     ^^                ^^^^               ^^               ^^^^
```

Only thing that was left was to adjust the backreferences for the different capture groups:

```
s/\(\sclass\s*=\s*"\)\(\([^"]*\)\( \)\)\?span\([0-9]\+\)\(\( \)\([^"]*\)\)\?"/\1\3\4col-md-\5\7\8"/g
                                                                                ^^^^         ^^^^
```

Comment: This is truly fantastic, thank you both for the regex and the explanation of how you got there. For anyone coming along later, this **doesn't** handle both `spanN`s in `<div class="span3 span9 arg">stuff here</div>`, it just handles the last one. That's fine for me, there shouldn't be two of these on the same element, but if you were applying this elsewhere, it may not work for you. It **does** handle `<div class="col-md-3 arg">This has span3 in it</div><div class="col-md-6 arg">This has span6 in it</div>` correctly. Terrific stuff.